# I Didn't Get The User Name I Asked For

Tags: support, display-names

When I signed up, I gave my desired screen name in the place where **John Doe** was used as an example. Instead of that name, I got the wimpy **user70330** instead.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **Edit Profile & Settings** option in your profile. There in the **Public Information** section you can see the **Display Name** textbox. Update your desired name in the box it will reflect in your account.

Link to your Meta Stack Exchange edit profile link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current

Comment: THANKS!!  It worked.  I am ... BORN2CODE